# Android: can I read IMEI using ADB.EXE?

Tags: android, adb, imei, serial-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an android shell or adb command that I could use to get a device's IMEI/MEID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852106/is-there-an-android-shell-or-adb-command-that-i-could-use-to-get-a-devices-imei)

I need to read the same value returned by TelephonyManager.getDevideId() from ADB.EXE command line. Is it possible?

I'll NOT use

```
adb get-serialno
```

because it returns the serial number, not he IMEI number.

Thanks.

Comment: refer to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852106/is-there-an-android-shell-or-adb-command-that-i-could-use-to-get-a-devices-imei

Comment: Very strange: adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo returns NULL as Device ID. Instead, using getDeviceId() I get a number...

Comment: What do you get by inputting *#06# from keyboard?
And, what brand/model is your Android phone?

Comment: Please refer to this link. The question has been previously asked.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android

Comment: This is a low cost Chinese tablet, no keyboard available: it's not a phone... But I expect getDeciveId() returns null, instead it returns a number that seems to be a correct IMEI. The command adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo returns NULL.

Comment: What is the output of *#06#. Maybe there is no IMEI written in the device

Comment: First, thank you for your interest for my question. Unfortunatelly I can't find the phone keyboard because it's a tablet not a phone. Maybe the phone keyboard apk is hidden.

Comment: Maybe there is no GSM/WCDMA module in the tablet therefore no IMEI at all

Comment: Sorry casperOne, you've closed this question but previous responses are not useful for my case. I need to know why java code gives the expected result while adb.exe doesn't. Mybe I need to post a more detailed question. Ok.

Comment: Hehe ok, but why getDeviceId() returns a correct IMEI?

Comment: I think, it is because your device does not implement some android APIs  complying regular rules

Comment: Yes I think so too, but no one seems to have faced this behaviour before...
This question has been closed. My new post (more specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518113/android-getdeviceid-returns-an-imei-adb-shell-dumpsys-iphonesubinfo-returns