# Android: getDeviceId() returns an IMEI, adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo returns Device ID=NULL

Tags: android, adb, imei

Different results for my low cost chinese tablet. It's not a phone so why getDeviceId() returns a number that seems to be a valid IMEI?

```
C:\>adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo
Phone Subscriber Info:
  Phone Type = GSM
  Device ID = null
```

but using

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

uid = 35881700... (I'm not showing the whole IMEI number for privacy)

Comment: Is there any kind of GSM radio in your tablet? (Sorry for posting an answer, but I am not allowed to post comments ..) According GSMPhone.java in the android version that I am looking at, the IMEI is set when the radio used by the device becomes initialized.

Comment: Hi, really I don't know if there's radio module inside the tablet hw. There's no phone keyboard app...

Comment: What does the log say about which hardware gets initialized when you start your tablet?

Comment: It looks like those China guys just return random IMEI in their firmware. Not in the first time, I saw also such IMEIs as "004999010640000000", "rkdroid_device0000", "FFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000". The only way is to check if device has cellular radio.