# Will this app show up in the Play Store?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I have heard in many places that if my app uses a permission not applicable to a certain device, it will not show up in the play store for that device. Now, in my code, I am playing audio. I mute that audio whenever there is a phone call by doing this:

```
 private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    onPhoneCallInterrupt(); //Method I made that mutes audio for phone call
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    onPhoneCallInterrupt(); //Method I made that mutes audio for phone call
                }
        }
    };
```

Now, this uses the following permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"  android:required="false" />
```

Will I get any exceptions because I have made the permission optional by doing `android:required = "false"` on devices that don't have phone compatibility (tablets)?

The reason I am so confused on this, is because I am checking if the phone is being used, but I am not using it. So, will my app work on tablets, let alone show up in the play store for them?

Thanks for helping me clear up this confusion,

Ruchir

Answer (score -2):

You have to use this way 
As your permission READ_PHONE_STATE request the

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
```

So you need to use this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
```

So play store wont filter your apps for the tablets 
but make sure you have to do check manually where you are using the functionality of the telephony that device is phone or tablets and have a telephony aceess or not

To check the telephony access device has or not use this check this code

```
static public boolean hasTelephony()
{
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) Hub.MainContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (tm == null)
        return false;

    //devices below are phones only
    if (Utils.getSDKVersion() < 5)
        return true;

    PackageManager pm = MainContext.getPackageManager();

    if (pm == null)
        return false;

    boolean retval = false;
    try
    {
        Class<?> [] parameters = new Class[1];
        parameters[0] = String.class;
        Method method = pm.getClass().getMethod("hasSystemFeature", parameters);
        Object [] parm = new Object[1];
        parm[0] = "android.hardware.telephony";
        Object retValue = method.invoke(pm, parm);
        if (retValue instanceof Boolean)
            retval = ((Boolean) retValue).booleanValue();
        else
            retval = false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        retval = false;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

For more you can check this blog 
http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/02/25/xoom-permissions-android-market.html

Comment: How do I check manually? I have been searching this for a long time now. I will mark you best answer and like your answer once I get this!

Comment: have you checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580590/how-to-find-out-whether-android-device-has-cellular-radio-module To check the manually if tablets have the telephony access or not

Comment: @RuchirBaronia once check this function i have updated my answer

Comment: So if a device doesn't have Telephony, it will be null?

Comment: Why should I replace `.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE ` with `.hardware.telephony`?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia because READ_PHONE_STATE comes under the telephony category

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I understand everything except the stuff that is in the try block. What does that code do? Can you explain? Thanks so much

Comment: @RuchirBaronia on any kind of error state means we dont get the telephony access so returning the false

Comment: What does `if (retValue instanceof Boolean)
            retval = ((Boolean) retValue).booleanValue();` do?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Checking this `method.invoke(pm, parm)` returns boolean or not. I suggest you should debug and test this code so you understand properly

Comment: @RuchirBaronia does it helped you or not ?