# Get/set imei number with adb for android phones

Tags: android, adb

I want to get/set an imei number for rooted android phone.

I tried this command

```
adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo
```

I tried this command also

```
adb shell getprop gsm.baseband.imei
```

I tried this command also

```
service call iphonesubinfo 1
```

Comment: Can you include in your question what you get when you try those commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the IMEI, of any of the forms.

For getting it via ADB, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852106/is-there-an-android-shell-or-adb-command-that-i-could-use-to-get-a-devices-imei)

Comment: Yes, but do we have any chance to get imei on above 5.0 versions?

Comment: Alright, Thnks, if possible try to answer this question, it would be helpful.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674477/can-we-do-below-operations-with-adb-in-android-mobile